# Java Applets with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, applet

I read all over the internet about GWT compilation of Java code into JavaScript.
I have an old applet code that I would like to translate into JavaScript. I am kinda lost in going from the typical applet functions (init, start stop, run .. etc) to GWT entry point class. Also, my applet is actually a game that heavily uses graphic package which I am not sure how that will translate by GWT
Does anyone have any pointers or sample code to guide me through this ?

Answer (score 2):

That's not going to work. GWT emulates only a [very small subset of the JRE](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) and provides a library of widgets and a RPC infrastructure for communicating with a server amongst other things. GWT is NOT a tool for porting Java applets or anything like that.

If you want to port your game to the modern web platform, I recomment using [PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/). It also has bindings for GWT.